# MySQL result set ordered by fixed positions

Tags: php, mysql

I've got following, simple table

```
Item (id, name, date, fixed_position)

(1, 'first entry', '2016-03-09 09:00:00', NULL)
(2, 'second entry', '2016-03-09 04:00:00', 1)
(3, 'third entry', '2016-03-09 05:00:00', NULL)
(4, 'fourth entry', '2016-03-09 19:00:00', NULL)
(5, 'fifth entry', '2016-03-09 13:00:00', 4)
(6, 'sixth entry', '2016-03-09 21:00:00', 2)
```

The number of items is not fixed, in fact can vary from ~100 to ~1000.

What i want to achieve is to perform a query to return set of Items ordered by `date` field which takes into consideration `fixed_position` field, which stands for something like "pinned" results to specific positions. If `fixed_position` for given entry is not NULL the result should be pinned to n-th position and if `fixed_position` is NULL the `ORDER BY` should take precedence.

Desired output of query for brighter explanation:

```
(2, 'second entry', '2016-03-09 04:00:00', 1)    // pinned to 1-st position
(6, 'sixth entry', '2016-03-09 21:00:00', 2)     // pinned to 2-nd position
(3, 'third entry', '2016-03-09 05:00:00', NULL)  // ORDER BY `date`
(5, 'fifth entry', '2016-03-09 13:00:00', 4)     // pinned to 4-th position
(1, 'first entry', '2016-03-09 09:00:00', NULL)  // ORDER BY `date`
(4, 'fourth entry', '2016-03-09 19:00:00', NULL) // ORDER BY `date`
```

I've tried solution posted in [Ordering MySql results when having fixed position for some items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16772183/ordering-mysql-results-when-having-fixed-position-for-some-items) but even with copy-paste method this doesn't seem to work at all.

What I've tried this far is this query:

```
SELECT
  @i := @i +1 AS iterator,
  t.*,
  COALESCE(t.fixed_position, @i) AS positionCalculated
FROM
  Item AS t,
  (
SELECT
  @i := 0
) AS foo
GROUP BY
  `id`
ORDER BY
  positionCalculated,
  `date` DESC
```

Which returns:

```
iterator | id | name        | date                | fixed_position | positionCalculated 
1          1    first entry   2016-03-09 09:00:00   NULL             1
2          2    second entry  2016-03-09 04:00:00   1                1
6          6    sixth entry   2016-03-09 21:00:00   2                2
3          3    third entry   2016-03-09 05:00:00   NULL             3
4          4    fourth entry  2016-03-09 19:00:00   NULL             4
5          5    fifth entry   2016-03-09 13:00:00   4                4
```

Does MySQL can perform such task or should I take backend approach and perform PHP's `array_merge()` on two result sets?

Comment: What is the SQL that you are using? So that we can see what you have tried. IE: `order by date,ifnull(fixed_position,0)`

Comment: I've added example query in my question. Spent more than 5 hours on this looking for an answer, ended up with almost nothing.

Comment: Is `fixed_position` a field in your table, or a calculated field?

Comment: What is the output of the query you posted?

Comment: @JacquesKoekemoer fixed_position is a field in table, which is described in question.

Comment: @SebastianŁuczak so try this SQL and see if it gives you the expected result: `select * from Item order by date,ifnull(fixed_position,999)`

Comment: @JacquesKoekemoer unfortunately i've tried this earlier and item with fixed_position = 2 goes to the end of result set, instead of 2-nd position.

Comment: The issue is your `NULL` valued fields, if you order it by `fixed_position` first and then `date` then your fields with `NULL` values in `fixed_position` will be at the end, unless you write a case statement in the `ifnull` function to calculate the fixed position based on the date. The other solution is to make `fixed_position` a `not null` field and order by `fixed_position` only. I can't think of any other way to make the results show in the way that you want them

Comment: Is there a fixed number of `fixed_position`s?

Comment: i can't test it on a database but what happens if you do this in the order by:  ifnull(t.fixed_position, positionCalculated+1) instead of just positionCalculated

Comment: @Doctus If fixed number of `fixed_positions` can solve this problem than we can assume, that `fixed_position` can take value {1-50}.

Comment: @valepu all entries with `fixed_position` NOT NULL went to the end of result set, which is odd but that's what happened.

Comment: You've not explained the logic of the ordering very well, omitted the data type of fixed_position and should have updated your question with the data range.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A brute force method to solve this would be to first create a tally table having an amount of rows bigger than the original table:

```sql
SELECT @rn := @rn + 1 AS rn
FROM (
   SELECT 1 AS x UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1) AS t1
CROSS JOIN (   
   SELECT 1 AS x UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1) AS t2
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn := 0) AS v
```

Then you can left join this table to a derived table containing all fixed positions of your original table:

```sql
SELECT Tally.rn
FROM (
   ... tally table query here 
) AS Tally
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT fixed_position
   FROM Item
) AS t ON Tally.rn = t.fixed_position
WHERE t.t.fixed_position IS NULL
```

The above returns the to-be-filled missing order positions.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/da4d39/1)

You can now use the above query as yet another derived table joined to the original table to achieve the desired ordering:

```sql
SELECT id, name, `date`, fixed_position, Gaps.rn, 
       derived.seq, Gaps.seq
FROM (
  SELECT id, name, `date`, fixed_position,
         @seq1 := IF(fixed_position IS NULL, @seq1 + 1, @seq1) AS seq
  FROM Item     
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @seq1 := 0) AS v
  ORDER BY `date`
 ) AS derived
LEFT JOIN ( 
    SELECT Tally.rn,
           @seq2 := @seq2 + 1 AS seq
    FROM (
      SELECT @rn := @rn + 1 AS rn
      FROM (
        SELECT 1 AS x UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1) AS t1
      CROSS JOIN (   
        SELECT 1 AS x UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1) AS t2
      CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn := 0) AS v
    ) AS Tally
    LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT fixed_position
      FROM Item
   ) AS t ON Tally.rn = t.fixed_position  
   CROSS JOIN (SELECT @seq2 := 0) AS v
   WHERE t.t.fixed_position IS NULL
   ORDER BY rn
 ) AS Gaps ON (derived.seq = Gaps.seq) AND (derived.fixed_position IS NULL)
 ORDER BY COALESCE(derived.fixed_position, Gaps.rn)
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/da4d39/14)

Comment: This is just perfect! Thank you, you've saved my day and countless work hours.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem (sort by date + inject rows with fixed position values). The above solution seems to work. But you have to know how much values your table has. The line:

`SELECT 1 AS x UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1`

has to get extended if you have more rows because the temporary table is to short. After some google search results and tests in my DB I've figured out a solution that fits your needs and is smarter to understand I think.

`SELECT *
FROM
    (SELECT 
            create_date,
            fixedposition,
            @rownum:=@rownum + 1 AS colposition,
            1 AS majorEntry
    FROM myTable
    JOIN (SELECT @rownum:=0) r
    WHERE fixedposition IS NULL
    ORDER BY crdate DESC) AS orderedFixed 
UNION ALL 
     (SELECT create_date,
            fixedposition,
            fixedposition AS colposition,
            0 AS majorEntry
    FROM myTable
    WHERE fixedposition IS NOT NULL
    ORDER BY fixedposition ASC)
ORDER BY colposition ASC, majorEntry`

So this is how it works: There are two SELECT statements. 
The first SELECT searches for all columns without a fixed position and sorts them by date. Additionally it makes a JOIN to add a row counter column.
The second one searches for all rows with a fixed position and returns the sorting by "colposition".

Both select statements gets combined by an UNION ALL. The union gets sorted first by the ASCending colposition and in the second step by the majonEntry-value which indicates that the rows with fixedposition are to be placed before the other rows which have the same position.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone stumbles upon this, I came up with a good solution with the help of dk1's answer. While his answer is good in principle, it has a flaw that every iteration of a pinned row has its position increased by one. For example: post pinned to the 1st position is on the 1st place (+0), post pinned to the 2nd position is on the 3rd place (+1), and post pinned to the 4th position is on the 6th place (+2).

I solved this by adding a second variable to decrease the final position of a pinned post.

Code explanation:

- `minor` = derived table with unpinned posts
- `major`= derived table with pinned posts
- `@rownum` = iterator for posts in minor table
- `@decrease` = iterator for posts in major table

```sql
SELECT
    final.*
FROM
    (
        (
            # see note #1 about this wrapper query
            SELECT * FROM
                (
                    SELECT
                        minor.*,
                        (@rownum := @rownum + 1) AS 'rowPosition',
                        0 AS 'rowDecrease',
                        0 AS 'majorEntry'
                    FROM table_with_your_posts minor
                    JOIN (@rownum := 0) x
                    WHERE minor.your_fixed_position IS NULL
                    ORDER BY minor.your_date DESC
                ) y
            ORDER BY y.your_date DESC
        )
        UNION ALL
        (
            SELECT
                major.*,
                major.your_fixed_position AS 'rowPosition',
                (@decrease := @decrease + 1) AS 'rowDecrease',
                1 AS 'majorEntry'
            FROM table_with_your_posts major
            JOIN (@decrease := -1) x
            WHERE major.your_fixed_position IS NOT NULL
            ORDER BY major.your_fixed_position ASC
        )
    ) final
# see note #2 about this ORDER BY clause
ORDER BY final.rowPosition - final.rowDecrease ASC, final.majorEntry DESC
```

note #1: Now I'm not an expert, but if you don't wrap the query of the minor table in another query and don't order it by the same thing as in the inner query, the sorting in the minor table just doesn't work. Maybe someone can shed more light on that.

note #2: `ORDER BY final.rowPosition - final.rowDecrease - final.majorEntry / 2 ASC` also works and looks cooler

Note that if you want to further filter your results (good example here would be to only show published posts), you will most likely need to add the filter condition to the WHERE clause of both the derived tables. Otherwise the final positions will be incorrect.

In the end I want to add that this isn't foolproof. For example if there are two pinned posts with the same position, it will shift the results by one. This could be solved by making the column with the fixed position UNIQUE. Other thing that comes to my mind is that if the table has less results than the position value of a pinned post, the post will obviously not be on its desired position (e.g. if the table contains 5 posts and you pin a post to the 8th position, it will probably end up being 5th). And remember that I didn't meaningfully test this, make sure your query is efficient for your needs.